# Sub Navigation wont slide down (CSS jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a responsive site and working on the mobilebuild. I have a menu bar and when you click on this the menu slides down. My only issue is now i have some sub menu items i want to add in and the jQuery and css i have is conflicting with what i am trying to do. Can someone see why this is not sliding down when i click on the menu item with the sub navigation?

Here is a link to how the menu kinda works: http://jsfiddle.net/ndT7H/1/

I am using the jQuery by:

```
$('ul#nav-2 > li > ul > li a').click(function () {
    $('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');
    if ($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').slideDown();
    }
});
```

I am using it from this example and have the code working in a separate file but not with the code i have for my current site.
http://jsfiddle.net/senff/9cK3X/3/

When this works i will have a + sign on the menu item to let users know to click and expand the menu and a minus when its open to slide the sub menu back up.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have an <h2> inside a <ul>.

Comment: Sorry that just was in there to show where to click to dropdown, i will update the link now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

#### Html

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('ul ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul#nav-2').find('> li > ul').slideToggle();
});

$('ul#nav-2  li  ul  li a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('ul').find('> li > .sub-menu').not($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').slideToggle()).slideUp('normal');
});
```

#### Css

```
#nav-2 > li > ul {
    background:#FFF;
    left:0;
    top:56px;
    position:relative;
    color:#000;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3tREU/)**

Comment: Nearly! Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/senff/9cK3X/3/ where the other menu items slide down when the sub menu slides down, I have this example working on a test page but not on my already implemented site.

Comment: Heya, i've checked your updated answer and the sub-navigation still overlays the main menu item rather than pushing it down? Great jQuery function though, simple and makes sense!

Comment: @user2212564 Thats your css. Really. you want to reconstruct the whole menu itself? That is not in your question.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, i will look through my css and your example. You've been great help and thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user2212564 Did you check the latest fiddle? that doesn't overlap?

Comment: Yeah i've had a look :) Thanks, there was just so many li/ul and getting confused with them making them responsive! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first remove !important from ul.sub-menu

```
ul.sub-menu {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:none ;
}
```

then use this script

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().find('ul ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul#nav-2').find('ul').first().slideToggle();
});

$('ul#nav-2 > li > ul > li a').click(function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('ul.sub-menu').slideUp('normal');
    if ($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').is(':hidden') == true) {
        $(this).next('ul.sub-menu').slideDown();
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE for this](http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/7zPtv/)